# Caching video files - Good practice or not

Tags: performance, caching, video, browser, bandwidth

Is it a good practice, to cache video(mp4) files in browser cache (just like static resources are cached), in terms of bandwidth usage and performance?

I am thinking that caching video files will increase the current tab size and increases RAM usage. Am I right in this aspect?

Please enlighten me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Caching video where?

Comment: @Evk In the browser cache

Comment: Why should caching such data increase the RAM usage? That's not where such data is stored

Comment: @NicoHaase I was assuming, the content of a browser tab, be it cache or non-cache, is  in RAM when the tab is active.

Answer (score 2):

Browser cache does not sit in the RAM.  It will be stored on the device - so no RAM or tab size concerns.

If a video is going to be reused often - saving it locally will have much better performance than downloading. In reality though, browser caches are pretty small, and if you are caching many videos - they will not persist very long in the cache.  This [article](https://andydavies.me/blog/2018/09/06/safari-caching-and-3rd-party-resources/) links to studies from FB and Yahoo on how long files sit in the cache.

That said - there are a lot of parameters in the cache header. I think the biggest win for video is the "public" header ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) reference). This lets the file be stored on a CDN or any part of the network.

Having the video stored on the CDN saves the bandwidth from your server, and also is very fast delivery to your user (just the 'last mile.')

TL;DR: Caching video won't hurt, but don't expect a huge lift from local cache.  That said - CDN caching could be a huge win for commonly watched videos.